# Over image text that only appears when hovering over the image

Tags: html, css, image, text, hover

I got some simple code to make text appear when I hover over an image, the problem I run into is that the hover hitbox is bigger than the image. I looked at my CSS and tried a lot but I can't find the right bit of code that I need to change.

CSS:

```
.container {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
}

.image {
opacity: 1;
display: block;
width: 30%;
height: 183px;
transition: .5s ease;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
transition: .5s ease;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {  
opacity: 1;
}

.over_image_text {
background-color: #6552c7;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class='container'>
                <img class="projects" src="../../images/spaceinvaders.jpg" alt="spaceinvaders"></a>
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="over_image_text">Read more about this project</div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are looking for is this class in your CSS:

```
.over_image_text {
    background-color: #6552c7;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

The part which is interesting for you is the last line `padding: 16px 32px;`.
Try decreasing the pixel values to the size which would fit for you. If that's not enough, then you can also decrease the `font-size` here.